# Implementing BeanPostProcessor in Factory class

Tags: java, spring

I am working on an application where we have to perform some validation on an object. So how i am planning is that we keep validation in separate classes and annotate them with a custom validation annotation. Now we have factory which implements BeanPostProcessor, it checks if the bean is annotated with that custom validation if so it adds that bean to the factory. Now could there be a case something like the validatorfactory could be null.

```
public class ValidationFactory implements BeanPostProcessor {
private Map<ValidationType, CustomValidation> validationMap = new HashMap<ValidationType, CustomValidation>();

@Override
public Object postProcessBeforeInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
    Class clazz = bean.getClass();
    if (clazz.isAnnotationPresent(Validation.class)) {
        Validation annotation = (Validation) clazz.getAnnotation(Validation.class);
        this.addValidation(annotation.validation(), (CustomValidation) bean);
    }

    return bean;
} 

}
```

My Validation Class

```
@Validation(validation = ValidationType.VERSION_MISMATCH)

@Component
public class VersionMismatchValidation implements CustomValidation{
//logic for validation
}
```

The purpose of this approach is that in future if any further validations are added, all the developer should do is created the validation and annotate it. Factory class should never be impacted

Comment: Aren't you rebuilding the JSR-303 (bean validation) extension mechanism with this?

Comment: As per my knowledge they are some specific validations like Email, NotNull. but i have many validations that i need to implement. For example i have a validation that cheks if the version in the incoming object is higher than that in DB (looks up in cache). If its lower raise an exception. Can you please highlight if there is a way to have custom validation in bean validation ?

Comment: @M.Deinum...i checked we can have custom validation, but i need them to be runtime paramterized, for e.g. my validation for version mismatch needs 2 entries one from cache and the current one, ny ideas on how can i achieve that ?